# Is there a complete cure for Limited Scleroderma?

Tags: dermatology

One of my cousins is diagnosed with [Limited Scleroderma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scleroderma). Is there a complete cure for it? If not, are there any suggestions on reducing the pain and lead a normal day-to-day life?

A wide range of suggestions and treatment methods were mentioned in various websites, but they didn't help as more choices led to more confusion. Since this is a site for health experts, it would be great if concise treatment/cure information is given.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no *complete* cure for Limited [Scleroderma](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scleroderma) (LS). Luckily, there are good ways that doctors can treat the symptoms of it and help prevent any complications.<sup>1,2,3</sup>

- **Topical treatments** - one of the complications of LS is skin ulcers; if these become infected, there are some topical treatments to stop them from spreading
- **Antacid drugs** - used to stop some of the heart problems that may come with LS, especially heartburn
- **Other drugs** - doctors may prescribe other drugs to prevent lung problems  and other heart problems
- **Physical Therapy** - stiff joints and skin are common problems with LS; physical therapy, mostly stretching, can help to keep your body flexible, including your face
- **Occupational Therapy** - helps overcome any problems that LS patients might have on a daily basis; ie: special toothbrushes and flossing devices help with any dental problems
- **Surgery** - surgery might need to be done to help with some complications, such as calcium deposits under the skin, red spots caused by swollen blood vessels, and possibly amputation of fingertips if and infection causes gangrene (unlikely as infections are usually stopped before they can spread)

<sub>[1] [Mayo Clinic](http://www.mayoclinic.org/diseases-conditions/crest-syndrome/basics/treatment/con-20031524)</sub>
<sub>[2] [JAMA Dermatology](http://archderm.jamanetwork.com/article.aspx?articleid=478648)</sub>
<sub>[3] [A randomized controlled study of low-dose UVA1, medium-dose UVA1, and narrowband UVB phototherapy in the treatment of localized scleroderma](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0190962205046074)</sub>

Comment: Downvoted because our answers should be more than just regurgitation of mayoclinic (webmd, etc)

Comment: @Zaralynda - You might reconsider? There is no cure for scleroderma (limited or systemic), the answer is exactly correct in this assertion.

Comment: @anongoodnurse the downvote isn't about correctness, but that in beta we should be trying to make more information accessable on the web, not just rewrite what's already available. Anyway, retracted the downvote with your addition of more sources

Comment: @Zaralynda I'll make sure to keep that in mind next time I answer